# JQuery validationEngine not working in WordPress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-validation-engine

I have a rather complicated form in a file I've named newuser.php. I am using a WordPress plugin that allows in post/page php to include the file inside a WordPress page (I'm using the Suffusion theme). I am also trying to develop my own plugin (first time) and I am using that to enqueue all the necessary script and css files. I am loading my javascript files in the footer and jquery itself is being loaded in the header.

As near as I can tell I have instantiated jquery.validationEngine correctly and given each form element the proper class. If I paste the "Personal Information" fieldset into an html doc with all the javascript, it works exactly how it's supposed to. However, inside the WordPress page absolutely nothing happens. I have spent the better part of two days trying to search for answers without success.

The page can be viewed here: http://uniquelyyours.blogdns.com/test/?id=I17 The ID reference is necessary for the form to work correctly. To test, use the radio button "My" and choose Grandfather as relation. Here is the code for the included php file with the form:

```
    <?php
$tng_folder = get_option('mbtng_path');
chdir($tng_folder);
include('begin.php');
include_once($cms['tngpath'] . "genlib.php");
include($cms['tngpath'] . "getlang.php");
include($cms['tngpath'] . "{$mylanguage}/text.php");
mbtng_db_connect() or exit;

$id = $_GET['id'];
//Check to make sure the variable has been passed correctly. If not, error message.
if (!isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo "<p style=\"color: #f00;\"><b>You can't register without showing your relationship in our tree ... Please go <a href=\"".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\">back and search for your relative first.</a></b></p><br/><br/>";
}

//Get the relevant row from the database
$select = "SELECT * FROM tng_people WHERE personID='$id' ";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$f = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$first = $f['firstname'];
$last = $f['lastname'];
$name = ($first.' '.$last) ;
$readonly = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"aname\" value=\"$name\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"40\" readonly=\"readonly\"/>";
$read = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"newid\" id=\"x\" value=\"$id\" readonly=\"readonly\"/>";
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/user-registration/success/?try=1";
$relation = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['relation']));
$aname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['aname']));
$personid = $_POST['newid'];

//Grab the posted variables
$whom = $_POST['whom'];
//parents
$father_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['father_firstname']));
$father_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['father_lastname']));
$father_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['father_birthdate']));
$mother_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['mother_firstname']));
$mother_maidenname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['mother_maidenname']));
$mother_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['mother_birthdate']));
$parents_mar_date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['parents_mar_date']));
//grandparents
$grandfather_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandfather_firstname']));
$grandfather_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandfather_lastname']));
$grandfather_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandfather_birthdate']));
$grandmother_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandmother_firstname']));
$grandmother_maidenname =mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes( $_POST['grandmother_maidenname']));
$grandmother_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandmother_birthdate']));
$grandparents_mar_date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['grandparents_mar_date']));
//great-grandparents
$gr_grandfather_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandfather_firstname']));
$gr_grandfather_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandfather_lastname']));
$gr_grandfather_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandfather_birthdate']));
$gr_grandmother_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandmother_firstname']));
$gr_grandmother_maidenname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandmother_maidenname']));
$gr_grandmother_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandmother_birthdate']));
$gr_grandparents_mar_date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['gr_grandparents_mar_date']));

//Spouse
$spouse_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['spouse_firstname']));
$spouse_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['spouse_lastname']));
$spouse_birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['spouse_birthdate']));
$spouse_birthplace = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['spouse_birthplace']));
$spouse_mar_date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['spouse_mar_date']));

//self
$first_name =  mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['first_name']));
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['last_name']));
$real_name = $_POST['first_name']." ".$_POST['last_name'];
$birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['birthdate']));
$birthplace = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['birthplace']));
$telephone = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['telephone']));
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['address']));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['city']));
$state_prov = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['state_prov']));
$postalcode = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['postalcode']));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['country']));
$user_url = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['user_url']));
$user_login = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['user_login']));
$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['user_email']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$user_pass = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['user_pass']));
$pass = md5($user_pass);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['pass']));
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['notes']));

//error message variables
$oops = 'Uh Oh. You missed a few items! Please complete the following missing information:<br /><br />';
$nofather_firstname = 'Please enter Father\'s first name.';
$nofather_lastname = 'Please enter Father\'s last name.';
$nofather_birthdate = 'Please enter Father\'s date of birth.';
$nomother_firstname = 'Please enter Mother\'s first name.';
$nomother_maidenname = 'Please enter Mother\'s maiden name.';
$nomother_birthdate = 'Please enter Mother\'s date of birth.';
$noparents_mar_date = 'What? Your parents never got married?';

$nograndfather_firstname = 'Please enter Grandfather\'s first name.';
$nograndfather_lastname = 'Please enter Grandfather\'s first name.';
$nograndfather_birthdate = 'Please enter Grandfather\'s date of birth.';
$nograndmother_firstname = 'Please enter Grandmother\'s first name.';
$nograndmother_maidenname = 'Please enter Grandmother\'s maiden name.';
$nograndmother_birthdate = 'Please enter Grandmother\'s date of birth.';
$nograndparents_mar_date = 'No way your parent was illegitimate!!';

$nogr_grandfather_firstname = 'Please enter Great Grandfather\'s first name.';
$nogr_grandfather_lastname = 'Please enter Great Grandfather\'s first name.';
$nogr_grandfather_birthdate = 'Please enter Great Grandfather\'s date of birth.';
$nogr_grandmother_firstname = 'Please enter Great Grandmother\'s first name.';
$nogr_grandmother_maidenname = 'Please enter Great Grandmother\'s maiden name.';
$nogr_grandmother_birthdate = 'Please enter Great Grandmother\'s date of birth.';
$nogr_grandparents_mar_date = 'Okay, I\'ll give you a pass on this one. But if you don\'t know, just put "unknown."';

$nospouse_firstname = 'Please enter your Spouse\'s first name.';
$nospouse_lastname = 'Please enter your Spouse\'s last name.';
$nospouse_birthdate = 'Please enter your Spouse\'s birthdate.';
$nospouse_birthplace = 'Please enter your Spouse\'s birthplace.';
$nospouse_mar_date = 'Please enter the date you entered into wedded bliss.';

$sendto_email = "heather@uniquelyyourshosting.com";
$admin_mess = "Congratz TNG Admin !!! A new user joined your site !!!\n\n";

//Parent Info Table
$opt = '
<fieldset>
    <legend>Parent\'s Information</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "father_firstname">Father\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="father_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="father_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "father_lastname">Father\'s Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="father_lastname" class="validate[required]" name="father_lastname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "father_birthdate">Father\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="father_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="father_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "mother_firstname">Mother\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="mother_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="mother_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "mother_maidenname">Mother\'s Maiden Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="mother_maidenname" class="validate[required]" name="mother_maidenname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "mother_birthdate">Mother\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="mother_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="mother_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <label for="parents_mar_date">Marriage Date for this couple</label>
            <input type="text" id="parents_mar_date" class="validate[required]" name="parents_mar_date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
';

//Add Grandparent Info
$opta = '
<fieldset>
    <legend>Grandparent\'s Information</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for "grandfather_firstname">Grandfather\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandfather_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="grandfather_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "grandfather_lastname">Grandfather\'s Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandfather_lastname" class="validate[required]" name="grandfather_lastname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "grandfather_birthdate">Grandfather\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandfather_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="grandfather_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "grandmother_firstname">Grandmother\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandmother_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="grandmother_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "grandmother_maidenname">Grandmother\'s Maiden Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandmother_maidenname" class="validate[required]" name="grandmother_maidenname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "grandmother_birthdate">Grandmother\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandmother_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="grandmother_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <label for="grandparents_mar_date">Marriage Date for this couple</label>
            <input type="text" id="grandparenst_mar_date" class="validate[required]" name="grandparents_mar_date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
';

//Add Great-Grandparent's Information
$optb = '
<fieldset>
    <legend>Great-Grandparent\'s Information</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for "gr_grandfather_firstname">Great-Grandfather\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandfather_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandfather_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "gr_grandfather_lastname">Great-Grandfather\'s Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandfather_lastname" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandfather_lastname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "gr_grandfather_birthdate">Great-Grandfather\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandfather_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandfather_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "gr_grandmother_firstname">Great-Grandmother\'s First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandmother_firstname" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandmother_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "gr_grandmother_maidenname">Great-Grandmother\'s Maiden Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandmother_maidenname" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandmother_maidenname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "gr_grandmother_birthdate">Great-Grandmother\'s Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandmother_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandmother_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <label for="gr_grandparents_mar_date">Marriage Date for this couple</label>
            <input type="text" id="gr_grandparenst_mar_date" class="validate[required]" name="gr_grandparenst_mar_date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").validationEngine();
    alert( $("#register").validationEngine('validate') );
   });
</script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="register" name="register">
<fieldset>
    <legend>How are you related to this person?</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="display: inline-block;"><?php echo $read.$readonly; ?></span>
            &nbsp;
            <span style="display: inline-block;">
            <label style="display: inline-block;" for="whom">is</label>
            <input id="whom" type ="radio" name="whom" selected="selected" class="validate[required]" value="My" onclick="document.getElementById ('spouse').style.display = 'none';">My &nbsp;
            <input id="whom" type ="radio" class="validate[required]" name="whom" onclick="document.getElementById ('spouse').style.display = 'block';" value="Spouse"/>My Spouse's
            </span>
            &nbsp;
            <span style="display: inline-block;">
            <select id="relation" name="relation" onchange="processAncestor();" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="Father">Father</option>
                <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                <option value="Sister of Father">Sister of Father</option>
                <option value="Sister of Mother">Sister of Mother</option>
                <option value="Brother of Father">Brother of Father</option>
                <option value="Brother of Mother">Brother of Mother</option>
                <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
                <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
                <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather</option>
                <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother</option>
                <option value="Great Grandfather">Great Grandfather</option>
                <option value="Great Grandmother">Great Grandmother</option>
                <option value="2nd Great Grandfather">2nd Great Grandfather</option>
                <option value="2nd Great Grandmother" >2nd Great Grandmother</option>
                <option value="Self">Self</option>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Relationship</option>
            </select>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">If none of the available relationships properly describes your relationship to this person, you will need to email us directly to explain.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<div id="opt">
<p>Please complete the following information about your/your spouses' parents:</p>
<p>If you selected Myself above, we are looking for your parents information. If you selected My Spouse above, then we are looking for your spouse's parents. All Fields are Required. Dates should be in Day Month Year format as follows: 01 Jan 1900.</p>
<?php echo $opt; ?>
</div>

<div id="opta">
<p>Please complete the following information about your/your spouses' grandparents:</p>
<?php echo $opta; ?>
</div>

<div id="optb">
<p>Please complete the following information about your/your spouses' great-grandparents:</p>
<?php echo $optb; ?>
</div>

<div id="spouse">
<br /><br />
<p>Please complete the following information about your spouse:</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "spouse_firstname">Spouse Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="spouse_firstname" class="validate[required] text-input" name="spouse_firstname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "spouse_lastname">Spouse Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="spouse_lastname" class="validate[required]" name="spouse_lastname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "spouse_birthdate">Spouse Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="spouse_birthdate" class="validate[required]" name="spouse_birthdate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for "spouse_birthplace">Spouse Location Of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="spouse_birthplace" class="validate[required]" name="spouse_birthplace" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for "md">Your Marriage Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="spouse_mar_date" class="validate[required]" name="spouse_mar_date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Information</legend>
<div id="self">
<p>Please complete the following information about yourself for the User Registration:
<br />An <strong>*</strong> indicates a <strong>Required</strong> field.</p>

<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <label for="first_name">First Name*</label>
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
            <input type="text" id="first_name" class="validate[required] text-input" name="first_name" />
        </td>
        <td width="60%"><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="last_name" class="validate[required] text-input" name="last_name" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="birthdate">Date of birth*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="birthdate" class="validate[required] text-input" name="birthdate" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="birthplace">Location of birth</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="birthplace" name="birthplace" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="telephone">Phone Number*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="telephone" class="validate[required]" name="telephone" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="address">Address*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" class="validate[required]" name="address" id="address" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="city">City*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="city" class="validate[required]" name="city" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="state_prov">State/Province*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="state_prov" class="validate[required]" name="state_prov" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="postalcode">Postal Code*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="postalcode" class="validate[required]" name="postalcode" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="country">Country*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="country" class="validate[required]" name="country" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="user_url">Your Website</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" name="user_url" id="user_url" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="user">Login Name*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" class="validate[required]" name="user_login" id="user_login" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Usernames cannot begin with a number and should not contain any punctuation characters (no . , : ; ' " ! \ / [ ] { } + - )
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="user_email">Email Address*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Please make sure you are not blocking mail from the this domain to ensure email from us does not end up in a spam or junk folder.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="email">Email Again*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" class="validate[required]" name="email" id="email" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="user_pass">Password*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" class="validate[required]" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Passwords should be at least 7 characters and include at least one Upper case letter, one lower case letter and one number/symbol.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="pass">Password Again*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" class="validate[required]" name="pass" id="pass" />
        </td>
        <td><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<label for="notes">Notes:</p>
<textarea cols="75" rows="5" name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
</div>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit User Registration" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The custom javascript for the relation select field is here:

```
    function processAncestor() {
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 0) {//father
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 1) {//mother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 2) {//sister of father
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 3) {//sister of mother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 4) {//brother of father
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 5) {//brother of mother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 6) {//brother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 7) {//sister
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 8) {//grandfather
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 9) {//grandmother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 10) {//great-grandfather
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 11) {//great-grandmother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 12) {//2gr-grandfather
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 13) {//2gr-grandmother
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("relation").selectedIndex == 14) {//self
        document.getElementById('opt').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('opta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('optb').style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

I would really appreciate help in figuring out why I can't get the validation script to function properly with this form in the Suffusion page. I suspect there is a JQuery/Javascript conflict somewhere but I am such a noob I tend to break things a lot! I also welcome any chance to learn from my breakages! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the jquery file you've included is calling [no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Try replacing your `$` in your jquery call to the validation engine with `jQuery`

You are getting an error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Property `$` of object [object Window] is not a function " which is consistent with this.

change the jquery to this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#register").validationEngine();
  alert( jQuery("#register").validationEngine('validate') );
});
```

and remove this

```
$.noConflict();
```

Comment: I read the various options for handling JQuery $ conflict. The easiest appeared to be `$.noConflict();` Unfortunately, that had no effect.

Comment: noconflict was already called.  you just need to replace the dollar sign with jQuery

Comment: Thank you!! That worked! Now I just need to set up the post processing to handle the success action. Right now it just reloads and shows the errors. But it works! I just learned how to call plugin functions correctly in WordPress!